# How do can you add titlecaps to starred sections in beamer metropolis theme?

Tags: beamer, beamer-metropolis

I am trying to add title caps to all section titles and frame titles in my presentation. If I use only numbered sections, everything works as expected but starred sections cannot be redefined the same way.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titlecaps}
\title{slides test}
\author{me}
\institute{}
\date{}
\usetheme{metropolis}

\makeatletter
\let\oldsection\section
\def\section#1{\oldsection{\titlecap{#1}}}
\let\oldframetitle\frametitle
\def\frametitle#1{\oldframetitle{\titlecap{#1}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction section}
\begin{frame}{First Frame}
Hello, world!
\end{frame}
\section*{Numberless section}
\begin{frame}{New frame}
I can add title caps to frame titles and regular sections but not starred sections.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

I'm working around it by resetting the section counter and printing tables of contents without section numbers, but I'd like to know how to make it work properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `\section` can take a star option, which means that it, by itself, takes no argument, but then calls on star/unstar versions that *do* take an argument.  You have to recreate this logic.

As it stands in the OP's code, the argument that `\section` is forced to take becomes the `*` option, instead of the desired argument that follows.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titlecaps}
\title{slides test}
\author{me}
\institute{}
\date{}
\usetheme{metropolis}

\makeatletter
\let\oldsection\section
\renewcommand\section{%
  \@ifstar
    {\Altsecstar}%
    {\Altsecnostar}%
}
\newcommand\Altsecstar[1]{\oldsection*{\titlecap{#1}}}
\newcommand\Altsecnostar[1]{\oldsection{\titlecap{#1}}}
\let\oldframetitle\frametitle
\def\frametitle#1{\oldframetitle{\titlecap{#1}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\section{Introduction section}
\begin{frame}{First Frame}
Hello, world!
\end{frame}
\section*{Numberless section}
\begin{frame}{New frame}
I can add title caps to frame titles and regular sections but not starred sections.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```